# Android - ListView with images scrolls not smooth

Tags: android, image, listview

I'm trying to to show a ListView with goods. **Goods** is a SQLite table with title, count and image (BLOB). So my ListView is not smooth.

What have I tried:

1. Open camera intent, capture, get Extras and insert to SQLite. So I have used only one bitmap. This method worked fine until number of Goods was less then 50.

I went by another way:

1. Open camera intent, capture and save to file.
2. Checking `ExifInterface` and rotate image if needed.
3. Scale using http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html to the size 300x300 and moving to my folder. This image file is for fullscreen.
4. Now I need a thumbnail to put it into ListView in future. So I scale file(3) to thumbnail size (for example 60x60) using `setPic()` method from http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html
   and save this small thumb to SQLite database **Goods** table.

Now ListView become scrolling hard when number of Goods is over 100. And this is not the problem solution.

So I need some different way to fill ListView with images.

Please, direct me in right way )))

Thanks!

P.S. I'm using custom SimpleCursorAdapter to show data:

```
public class GoodsCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
    public GoodsCursorAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.cell_goods, null,
                new String[] { "title", "countAvail" },
                new int[] { R.id.lbTitle, R.id.lbCount }, 0);

    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView lbTitle, lbCount;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cell_goods, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivThumb);
            viewHolder.lbTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lbTitle);
            viewHolder.lbCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lbCount);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        mainCursor.moveToPosition(position);
        byte[] byteArray = mainCursor.getBlob(mainCursor.getColumnIndex("photo"));
        if (byteArray != null) {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
            Log.d("INFO", mainCursor.getString(mainCursor.getColumnIndex("title"))+": "+String.valueOf(bitmap.getWidth())+"x"+String.valueOf(bitmap.getHeight())+"("+String.valueOf(bitmap.getByteCount()/1024)+"Kb)");
            viewHolder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } else {
            viewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_picture);
        }
        viewHolder.lbTitle.setText(mainCursor.getString(mainCursor.getColumnIndex("title")));
        viewHolder.lbCount.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.lbCount), mainCursor.getString(mainCursor.getColumnIndex("countAvail"))));

        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: Check out this : http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: @HareshChhelana: I already use this method for scaling, see my question :)  May be I can use this in my `getView()`?

Comment: Yes, try to use in getView().

Comment: try one more thing load all bitmaps outside getview() either in constructor or rather outside adapter then assign it to adapter. Loading image every time from database when view is created may slow down the scroll.

Comment: @user4153589,If all bitmap loaded initially then it may cos Out of memory exception.

Comment: how many images are there?

Comment: already its thumb size image if number of images not greater than 20 or 30 I don't think it will cause memory leaks.

Comment: @HareshChhelana, Thank you, I will try your method and write about results

Comment: @HareshChhelana: I have tried to scale image in `getView()` and scrolling become a better, but still not smooth :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, I have tried almost all methods you suggested. And here is my report:

1. @HareshChhelana's method is use `inSampleSize` option (from `BitmapFactory.Options`). Method is **better** then storing small thumbnail in SQLite (as I have done first), but become not smooth for more then 200 list items with images
2. @Zain's suggestion to use Google solution (http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html). **This also works fine.**
3. Pagination from @Prachi. **Works fine.** But I did not add any logic to load next batch on listview's onscroll. My solution was: fetch first 30 rows and as use "Next 30 rows" and "Prev 30 rows" button. As this method was the last solution for me if no one methods without pagination won't work, I skip it. :)
4. @Pankaj's suggestion. I walked through this class and **it looks like working solution**, but I did not try it. Anyway answer is useful.

**I have found a library, which I used in my project:
https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader
It's really great and have a lot of useful settings!**

P.S. Sorry for my english :)

Answer (score 2):

Trying loading the images off the UI thread - using an AsyncTask.

Something like this (taken from [here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html))

```
class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<Cursor, Void, Bitmap> {
private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
private Cursor mCursor;;

public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView) {
    // Use a WeakReference to ensure the ImageView can be garbage collected
    imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
}

// Decode image in background.
@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(Cursor... params) {
    mCursor = params[0];
    byte[] byteArray = mCursor.getBlob(mCursor.getColumnIndex("photo"));
    if (byteArray != null) {
     Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
    return bitmap;
  }
}

// Once complete, see if ImageView is still around and set bitmap.
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null) {
        final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
        if (imageView != null) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

So modify

```
 if (byteArray != null) {     
  BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(imageView);
  task.execute(mainCursor);
 }else{......}
```

Comment: mm.. did not understand how to adapt `onPostExecute ` to LitView item.. Can you give more detailed explanation?

Comment: @Zain You'd also want to increase the size of the thread pool(other wise there will be a lag in image decoding since Executor by default has only one thread post Android 4, or 3. Also a check to prevent issues due to view recycling will be needed.

Comment: I've modified the code above to something you can use now. 
@Amit True on both accounts, but for the moment, if Romowski can get it to work, and be smoother, he can look at Thread Pool size and Cell re-use.

Answer (score 1):

Use lazy list for downloading image in listview.
Ref link: http://www.prandroid.com/2014/07/how-to-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview.html

Comment: ooh.. and replace `download from web` function to my `download from SD and scale` function. Right?

Comment: Yeah right. Lazy list downloading is nothing but the asynctask to work heavy work based on priority.

Answer (score 1):

Use pagination ..fetch 5/10 rows and to load bitmaps use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)
or you can load bitmap in async

**EDIT**

```
mListView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                if (scrollState == 1) {
                    isUserScroll = true;
                } else {
                    isUserScroll = false;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

                if (isUserScroll) {

                    int lastInScreen = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
                    if (!isDataLoading && (lastInScreen == totalItemCount)) {
                       //load data

                        isDataLoading = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: I thought about pagination, but not found some articles about.. And how to visualize pagination in ListView?

Comment: you can add logic to load next batch on listview's onscroll

Answer (score 0):

Load all bitmaps outside getview() either in constructor or rather outside adapter then assign it to adapter. Loading image every time from database when view is created may slow down the scroll.

In case you face any memory issue In preloding Images try caching them on memory
instead of saving to database

Comment: Thank you for reply, but number of images may be about 1-2 thousands  ))

Comment: Then dont save inside database cache them and save only urls to database